# Fazer um jogo em C# do zero

Tags: c#

Estou a aprender C#, e já tenho conhecimento suficiente(eu acho) para fazer um jogo simples 2D. Mas eu não quero usar NENHUMA engine. Portanto, por onde começo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mesmo você não querendo usar uma engine será necessário utilizar alguma biblioteca.

Como início você deve responder duas perguntas: 

Para qual plataforma será o jogo feito?(Mobile,pc,ps4,etc) 

Qual linguagem irá utilizar?

Tendo estas duas perguntas respondidas você deverá procurar alguma biblioteca gráfica que se encaixem em suas necessidades.

Após escolher sua biblioteca gráfica você já poderá iniciar a criação do core do seu jogo.

No core você irá desenvolver toda a base necessária para este e futuros jogos a serem desenvolvidos. Aqui entrará toda a gerência de dados(saves/loads), comunicação(cliente/servidor caso necessário), gerência de telas, física(caso se aplique), ferramentas e integrações necessárias com as suas bibliotecas.

Como você está perguntando por onde começar creio que é no core que deves focar.

**Sistema Gráfico**

Eu recomendaria então inciar fazendo seu sistema gráfico, onde irá controlar a maneira que seu jogo utiliza a sua biblioteca gráfica, após este passo completo você deverá conseguir ter uma janela e poder desenhar imagens e formas geométricas com múltiplas cores. 
Após isto você poderá começar a trabalhar na estrutura base do seu core, lembrando que no core você só irá aplicar coisas que poderão ser utilizadas em múltiplos jogos.

**Core**

No core do seu jogo você terá coisas como o GameLoop, gerência de eventos, estruturas básicas de dados e quaisquer ferramentas que você achar necessário para o desenvolvimento de um jogo. Neste passo lhe recomendo dar uma lida neste livro : http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/contents.html
 aqui são mostrado vários patterns que poderão ser colocados no seu core.

**Física**

A física é um ponto delicado, pois existe a opção de utilizares uma engine pronta que irá provavelmente funcionar melhor que uma engine física autoral e irá tomar muito menos tempo. Caso queiras desenvolver a sua própria engine recomendo leres sobre o desenvolvimento de engines físicas pois elas podem se tornar muito complexas.

Com estes pontos implementados e funcionando já podes começar a trabalhar no seu jogo de fato.

Eu acredito que só devemos desenvolver um jogo do zero sem utilizar engines em duas situações:

- Para aprendizado, deste modo você entenderá melhor como as engines
  funcionam e saberá lidar melhor com problemas a surgirem no futuro.
- Nenhuma engine cumpre os requisitos do seu jogo, este caso é mais
  raro em desenvolvedores indies mas é comum na grandes industrias de
  jogos, onde os melhores engines não conseguem rodar os requisitos dos
  jogos projetados de maneira satisfatória.

Tirando esses dois casos eu recomendo sempre utilizar uma engine, seja ela Unreal, Unity, CryEngine, etc.
Elas foram feitas para facilitar a vida do desenvolvedor e são bem poderosas.

Comment: Obrigado por esta resposta! Simplesmente falou sobre exatamente o que eu queria, mas não sabia como o colocar em questão. Obrigado! Caso queira saber, eu estou a fazer isto para aprender mais.

Comment: Já agora, agora estou com um problema. Ando à procura de bibliotecas gráficas... Mas não encontro nenhuma simples... Já tentei o OpenGL mas é demasiado complexo para o que eu quero fazer....